# Match the HTML <link> tag with given href attribute with regex

Tags: php, regex, dom

First, I want to say, that I do not try to parse `HTML` with regular expressions, so do not advise me to use PHP DOM, however I have tried to use it, but in my case the PHP `DOMDocument` mess up the final `HTML` markup, because in contains in-line `JavaScript` and `jQuery` dynamic tag generation and/or content replacement, for example, like:

`$("#status-message").show(200).html("<div style=''>...</div>")`

Moving the in-line `JavaScript`/`jQuery` code from the input `HTML` string to external `.js` file for inclusion is **not** an option (although this *may* solve the issue with PHP `DOMDocument`).

By using PHP `DOMDocument` the final markup gets replaced with **entities** on `saveHTML()` method (which produces invalid code, of course), for example, like:

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
  var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; zero)).join("0") + num;
}
```

**This is the reason to try to match given tag only ** with **regex** from the input `HTML` string, remove it and return modified `HTML` string as well (the input `HTML` string in most cases may be a valid `HTML`).

This is my code with the **regex** so far:

```
<?php
 $html = "<html>
 <head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css'>
 </head>
 <!-- A LOT OF STUF HERE--></html>";
//The URL
 $url = preg_quote("http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css");
//The pattern
 $pattern = "~<link\s+[href=".$url."][^>]*>~i";
//The output
 $output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $html);
?>
```

1. I'm trying to match a given `<link>` (*case insensitive*) tag in `<head>` or `<body>` section (even if it is invalid markup when placed in `<body>`) with given `href` attribute, equals to  given URL.
2. The placement of the `href` attribute can be anywhere in the tag, also the `<link>` tag can be self-closed or not (i.e. all of them must be matched).
3. I do not care if there are more that 1 `href` attributes in the `<link>` tag (although this will be also invalid markup) (i.e. all of them must be matched)..
4. I do not care if there is more that 1 `<link>` tag with the same `href` attribute (i.e. all of them must be matched).
5. The contents of the `href` attribute can be quoted with **single** quotes, **double** quotes or **not quoted** at all, or, even it is invalid markup can miss a quote, or have a mix of single/double/no quotes (i.e. all of them must be matched).

Example of valid matches:

```
<link    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css">
<link href='http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css">
```

**EDIT (new valid examples):**

```
<LinK    href=http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css />
<link  
  href=http://www.example.com/themes/css.min.css />
```

This is driving me crazy for couple of days and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = preg_quote($url, '/');

echo preg_replace('/<link([^>]*?)href[\s]?=[\s]?[\'\"\\\]*'.$url.'([^>]*?)>/is', '', $html);
```

See it in action https://eval.in/118665

Comment: Nope, see here: https://eval.in/118670 , it will match something which is not needed (the `ss` from the `n.css`).

Comment: It is not matching, its replacing, thats all.. It replaced all that was matched

Comment: OP wants to replace all the matches and show the content which did not match. Thats what it does

Comment: I`m the OP actually :) Maybe I was not clear in my question: I need to match the whole given URL, not a part from it (i.e. `n.css`, but not only the `ss` from the example in above comment) and replace the whole `<link>` tag.

Comment: So what is the the output you are expecting? an array of all matches? I though you want to get rid of all the `<link>` tags which has a given URL in it

Comment: From the question `...  from the input HTML string, remove it and return modified HTML ..`

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all `<link>` tags, but only if they match the whole given URL (not only a when a part from it matches, as you can see in given example in above comment). Of course, before removing the `<link>` tags, they first needs to be matched.

Comment: ok now I got what you are telling, But since, as you say, the markup can be invalid with or without quotes, this will be a challenge

Comment: Yes, indeed, please edit your answer in order to place this new pattern, so everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: Although there is a problem if the `<link>` is placed on multiple lines, see the edit of the question.

Comment: Try this https://eval.in/119229 I have added `s` modifier for matching newline and changed `.*?` to `[^>]*?`. However now if you have a link tag which does not have a closing `>`, then this will not match it.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you want, and I will update the answer

Comment: Yes, now it is perfect, if the `<link>` tag does not have closing bracket, then even the browser itself will not interpret it as `link`, so it is OK. I will accept your answer, thank you for your help!